Troubleshooting TypeError in Stripe integration with Laravel Livewire component
I'm working on a project where I'm integrating Stripe. Everything works fine until I call the addPaymentMethod method of the PaymentMethod component.
Here is the code for the component:
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class PaymentMethod extends Component
{
    public function addPaymentMethod($paymentMethod){
        auth()->user()->addPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.payment-method', [
            'intent' => auth()->user()->createSetupIntent()
        ]);
    }
}

And here is the relevant part of the Blade file:
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <!-- ... -->
    <script>
        const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
        const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
        const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
        
        cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
            const { 
                setupIntent, 
                error 
            } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
                clientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                        card: cardElement,
                        billing_details: { 
                            name: cardHolderName.value 
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        
            if (error) {
                // Handle error
            } else {
                console.log(setupIntent.payment_method);
                @this.addPaymentMethod(setupIntent.payment_method);
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>

Everything works as expected until the following line is executed:
@this.addPaymentMethod(setupIntent.payment_method);

This results in the following error in the console:

billings:187 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties
of undefined (reading 'find') at HTMLButtonElement.
(billings:187:33)

When I inspect the details, it shows me this. I've checked, and the setupIntent.payment_method property returns a correct value. I've been looking into this, but I need help finding the source of my error. Can anyone help?

"I've checked, and the setupIntent.payment_method property returns a correct value." - that part is not the problem, according to what your screenshot shows. The attempt to call window.livewire.find fails - because window.lifewire is undefined.
